# node.js and expo are installed but expo is not working. I can't connect from my device

Tags: node.js, json, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I could see the snaks I made with expo.dev on my mobile device. I was starting the project with visual studio code for the first time, but when I scanned the QR code on my mobile device, "there was a problem loading the requested app. the request timed out. it looks like you may be using a LAN URL. make sure your device is on the same network as the server, and that you have granted Expo Go the Local Network permission in the setting app, or try using the tunnel connection type." warning is coming. Localhost does not appear under the QR code. node.js and expo are installed but expo is not working.

Comment: Dit you find a solution?